# Why do I get a timeout when I connect via ssh to a Cisco ASA, even though management and ACLs are configured?

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, ssh

I set up a Cisco ASA 5505 8.4(3), and

- specified `ssh version 2`
- enabled ssh access to the WAN interface via `ssh <my network> <mask> <WAN interface>`
- allowed ssh from my network via an ACL
- my user account has privilege 15 with full access, including ssh

I did similarly for ASDM and it worked. However, when connection via ssh, I get:

```
ssh: connect to host <name> port 22: Connection timed out
```

I checked the log via the ASDM, which confirmed that there's a connection, but ending with an error message:

> SSH session from  on interface  for user ""
>   disconnected by SSH server, reason: "Internal error" (0x00)

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin I got a lot of such "Did any answer help you?" posts in my now spammy inbox. It requires action. Deleting my posts can help too.

Comment: I don't want to simply delete questions for which an answer may be expected, and many have good answers, just none are accepted. The goal is to get accepted answers for the archive. I don't mean to spam you, but you may have a bunch of questions that were answered, and you never accepted any. If you got a helpful answer to a question, you should accept it so that the person who took the time to answer you is rewarded, and the question doesn't keep popping up to the top forever, looking for an answer you already have.

Comment: @RonMaupin OMG! So 5 of my questions are not marked as "answered". 4 of them I answered myself. At that time, I found it inappropriate to discourage other answers by accepting my own one. I could today, it's just the bunch of copies of the same request for every single question in my inbox.

Comment: The questions with answers that have not been accepted are getting this. In essence, you are asking the same, apparently answered, question over and over. If you accept an answer, then you are no longer "spamming" [networkengineering.se], and you will not get these messages.

Comment: @RonMaupin So you seriously say "then you are no longer "spamming" Network Engineering"? I'm spamming? **You are spamming**. See the screenshot below in my answer.

Comment: As I explained, your questions without accepted answers will keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. You will not get any messages if you simply accept an answer, which are apparently acceptable to you. I'm sorry if you got a bunch of messages, but the way SE works is that you accept an answer that is helpful to you, otherwise your question keeps popping to the top, looking for an answer.

Comment: If you have a problem with this, the place to discuss it is in [meta].

Comment: @RonMaupin I did not have a problem and don't have one now. I can ignore it. Btw. the "Unanswered" tab filters for "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers". The SE system is clever enough to not consider questions with upvoted answers as "unanswered popping up" even if they don't have the "tick". Where do questions without a tick "keep popping to the top" (menu, tab, link)?

Comment: For someone with no problem, you sure complain a lot. We get questions with unaccepted answers popping up all the time. Several people have asked if I could do something about it, so I have been placing a comment on all those types of questions. It so happens that you have a bunch because you have not been courteous enough to accept an answer. I am simply looking at the questions; I am not doing this by user. That is why you got a bunch of messages. I will not simply delete such questions because they serve the purpose of the SE archive. You can simply ignore the messages.

Comment: In fact, many people have accepted answers and thanked me for reminding them. You are the only one to complain to me, so far.

Comment: @Ron Getting a few reminders was ok. I marked answers as solutions. Then more copies of the same text came in my inbox, and getting repeated messages with the same texts starts to get annoying. If NE users and SE staff like it to have 1000s redundant mod comments in the database, fine. I mentioned my opinion about that, finished for me. :-)

Comment: OK. You got a message per question because I am commenting on the questions, not by user. I started with the oldest questions.

Comment: @RonMaupin Perhaps continue per question (easier to filter) but just one message per user.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately the ASA doesn't show a good explanation in the error message. It's required to create an RSA key on the ASA, either via console or command line in the ASDM, executing the command [`crypto key generate rsa`](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa84/command/reference/c5.html#wp2270912), for example with highest possible modulus size:

```
crypto key generate rsa modulus 2048
```

in global configuration mode. The default modulus would be 1024.

With the ASDM it can also be done in the configuration menu, device management, identity certificates, add, new:

[image: ASDM key generation]

Since the other requirements were already met, the connection should be successful.

Since I cannot add images to comments to the question above, here a screenshot about mass bumping comment spam starting with one to this question and answer. That's a screenshot of moderator activity, no action by me.

[image: comment spam]

Comment: Whereas other OS's auto generate keys when the SSH daemon is started, or in the case of a client the first time you try and connect unfortunately the ASA software doesn't give you any pointers or generate one automatically.

Comment: well the Cisco IOS doesn't automatically generate the SSH cert either. you also need to type #crypto key generate rsa modulus 2048 then you can type $ip ssh version 2

Comment: technically, it shouldn't enable ssh unless it has a valid cert. I've never seen one start sshd without a cert.

Comment: I beat my head against this every time I deploy a new ASA.  I always forget that everything looks fine in the config, but until you generate the RSA key it looks like an ACL issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. `asa(config)# crypto key generate rsa general-keys modulus 2048`

   If you don't have user accounts already then configure below two line 2-3.
2. `asa(config)# username ash password ash privi 15`
3. `asa(config)# enable password cisco123`

   To Allow Access from inside network
4. `asa(config)# ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 inside`   (To Allow anyone from inside)

   To Allow Access from outside network
5. `asa(config)# ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside`   (To Allow anyone from Outside)

   the system should know where your useraccounts are:
   For lookup in Local Database
6. `asa(config)# aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL`   ------   Case sensitive (`LOCAL` must be in capital, not `Local` or `local`)
7. `asa(config)# ssh version 2`